# How can I make vim recognize when to <Enter> on autocomplete?

Tags: vimrc, autocompletion

Im using TabNine YCM fork [vim plugin](https://github.com/codota/tabnine-vim).

I'm getting cool suggestions and all, but it's super annoying that it doesn't `<Enter>` when it should, instead, outputs NULL ASCII Code `^@`

[image: Example]

Is this related to some config part that I missed?

Any help?

Comment: Looks like the plugin doesn't handle newlines correctly. I would open an issue with the plugin

Comment: Already did, asked here to double-check if it's something else
If I have time I'll try to investigate see if I can fix it or something 
Thank you!